# What is the best way to have "holding text" before user input?

Tags: r, shiny

Apologies if this is documented somewhere, but I have struggled to find anything useful.

I have a shiny app where the user uploads a `.csv` file, which then appears in the UI using `DT::renderDataTable()` and `DT::dataTableOutput()`. What is the best way to have some holding text appear (e.g. "Please upload csv") in this panel until the user actually uploads their file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `validate` function seems to correspond to what you want. Check [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html) to have more details and to customize the error message.

You need to upload an Excel file in the following example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(readxl)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("Example"),

    sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("upload", "Upload a file")
    ),

    mainPanel(
        dataTableOutput("table")
            )
    )


server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$table <- renderDataTable({
        validate(need(input$upload != "", "Please select a data set"))
       read_xlsx(input$upload$datapath, sheet = 1)
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```